# Should I use ThreadLocal in this high traffic multi-threaded scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, threadpool, thread-local

**Scenario**

We are developing an API that will handle around 2-3 million hits **per hour** in a multi-threaded environment. The server is Apache Tomcat 7.0.64.

We have a custom object with lot of data let's call it XYZDataContext. When a new request comes in we associate XYZDataContext object to the request context. One XYZDataContext object per request. We will be spawning various threads in parallel to serve that request to collect/process data from/into XYZDataContext object. Our threads that will process things in parallel need access to this XYZDataContext object and 
to avoid passing around of this object everywhere in the application, to various objects/methods/threads, 
we are thinking to make it a threadlocal. Threads will use data from XYZDataContext object and will also update data in this object. 
When the thread finishes we are planning to merge the data from the updated XYZDataContext object in the spawned child thread into the main thread's XYZDataContext object.

**My questions:**

1. Is this a good approach?
2. Threadpool risks - Tomcat server will maintain a threadpool and I read that using threadlocal with thread pools is a disaster because thread is not GCed per say and is reused so the references to the threadlocal objects will not get GCed and will result in storing huge objects in memory that we don't need anymore eventually resulting into OutOfMemory  issues...

   UNLESS they are referenced as weak references so that get GCed immediately.
   We're using Java 1.7 open JDK. I saw the source code for ThreadLocal and the although the `ThreadLocalMap.Entry` is a weakreference it's not associated with a ReferenceQueue, and the comment for Entry constructor says "*since reference queues are not used, stale entries are guaranteed to be removed only when the table starts running out of space.*"

   I guess this works great in case of caches but is not the best thing in our case. I would like that the threadlocal XYZDataContext object be GCed immediately. Will the `ThreadLocal.remove()` method be effective here? 
   Is there any way to enforce emptying the space in the next GC run?
3. This is a right scenario to use ThreadLocal objects? Or are we abusing the threadlocal concept and using it where it shouldn't be used?

Comment: It is fine. Don't worry about GC, as long as you remove() it promptly.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling tells me you're on the wrong path. Since you already have a central context object (one for all threads) and you want to access it from multiple threads at the same time I would go with a Singleton hosting the context object and providing threadsafe methods to access it.

Instead of manipulating multiple properties of your context object, I would strongly suggest to do all manipulations at the same time. Best would be if you pass only one object containing all the properties you want to change in your context object.

e.g

```
Singleton.getInstance().adjustContext(ContextAdjuster contextAdjuster)
```

You might also want to consider using a threadsafe queue, filling it up with `ContextAdjuster` objects from your threads and finally processing it in the Context's thread.

Google for things like Concurrent, Blocking and Nonblocking Queue in Java. I am sure you'll find tons of example code.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion  (threadsafe queue + contextAdjuster) Will think about that. Also, I have updated the question a little to give more details - XYZDataContext will be initialized when a new request comes in, and will reside in request context. And asked if ThreadLocal.remove() can make any difference?  - just FYI.  Thank you.

Comment: Not sure any more if i understand you correctly. you have only one context object, right? Connection between Context and Context-Adjuster could be done as Visitor pattern.

Comment: One XYZDataContext object per request. We will be spawning various threads in parallel to serve that request to collect/process data from/into XYZDataContext object. Hope I answered your doubt.

Comment: Tthanks for clarification. In this case the contxt object must reside in the request and not in a singleton. Same principles apply as before. Only difference is, that you have one context/request and not one context/server instance. I did some Blocking Nonblocking programming recently. It's quite painful if you don't do it every day ;)

Comment: Got it, awesome thanks! And to put this into perspective of the approach I described in the scenario above, you mean to say that all the threads will produce the ContextAdjuster objects with the data they want to update into the XYZDataContext, then will insert ContextAdjuster objects into a queue and then finish and quit? And then this queue will be processed by some processor independently and will update the XYZDataContext processing   ContextAdjuster objects one by one?